# Substituting for the variable in a standard taylor series

Tags: polynomials, taylor-expansion

I'm trying to show that 4/(3x+1)=1/(1+(3/4)(x-1)) so i can then find the taylor series for the function f(x)=4/3x+1 and determne an interval of validity

I know 4/3x+1 is similar to 1/(1-x) for which there is a standard taylor series and will allow me to find the series so i rearranged 4/3x+1 to 4/1+3x so it reads as the standard taylor series. 
i then replace each occcurence of x by -3x to get:
4/1-(-3x) i then divide by 4 to get 1/((1/4)-(-3/4x))
but this doesn't match and I don't know where i'm going wrong or what the correct steps are so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: To show that $\frac{4}{1+3x}=\frac{1}{1+(3/4)(x-1)}$, you can bring  $1+(3/4)(x-1)$ to a common denominator $4$, getting $\frac{4+3(x-1)}{4}$, which is $\frac{3x+1}{4}$. Your calculation was correct, but led to $4\cdot \frac{1}{1-(-3x)}$. This can be used to express our function as a series in powers of $x$. You are being asked to express our function as a series in powers of $x-1$.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. i don't see where it leads on to prove the initial equation 4/(3x+1)=1/(1+(3/4)(x-1))